# VB.NET MENUSTRIP doesnt honor ImageScaling at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menustrip

I am trying to implement a 'Flag' w/ a menustrip.

I have an image list w/ a red flag and a black flag.

When I click the menu item, i want to toggle the image. 
The problem I have is that once I change the image, it wants to do SizeToFit which makes the Icon roughly the height of text.  I dont want that. I want the Image to be its actual size.

I have tried putting the statements in different orders, nothing i have tried seems to work.

Currently, I have the button set to the black flag at design time.
 This code shows me trying to change to a Red flag.

```
 tsbFlagPatient.Image = ilFlags.Images(1)
 tsbFlagPatient.ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None
 tsbFlagPatient.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
```

[If there is some better way to approach toggling the image, im open to that. That seems like a separate question. ]

Comment: If `ilFlags` is an `ImageList` you might want to revisit that.  It only returns a single sized image based on the size properties.

Comment: @plutonix - the 2 icons are the same size. one is red, one is black. why is this an issue trying to toggle them?  does this somehow keep me from doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make ImageScrolling work. 
Since I dont need text here, I used BackGround Image and set

```
BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch
```

This allows the images to be the right size. 
You can turn AutoSize = false and then manually set Height, Width  to fine tune your menu's size.

I did reconsider the ImageList and changed the images to being stored in the project Resources. This is the code to toggle the image

```
Public Sub SetFlagImage(flagSet As Boolean)
    If flagSet = False Then
        btnFlag.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.appbar_flag_wavy_black
        btnFlag.BackgroundImage.Tag = "black"
    Else
        btnFlag.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.appbar_flag_wavy_red
        btnFlag.BackgroundImage.Tag = "red"
    End If
End Sub
```

This had no effect on the question posed here. In general, probably better than having an image list because all forms can access it.